# Using Oracle XE and JSF 2.2 to enter data to the database by sorting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am coding a project with using JSF 2.2 and Oracle 11g XE I made connections statements etc. and can enter data to database. And also show data in the database to the user in view part called Web Pages. My problem is this: normally if you enter data with Oracle XE interface, you will see data -which you entered- ordered by id. But when I entered data with using JSF, in database I do not see any order.
For example

ID  NAME            SURNAME

1     Dan             Brown

2   Joanne Kathleen Rowling

3   George R.R      Martin

Normally this should be written in database. But in my case it is like this:

ID  NAME            SURNAME

1   Dan             Brown

**3 George R.R      Martin**

2   Joanne Kathleen Rowling

My code is:

```
public String AuthorEkle()//Sayfadan girilen verileri veri tabanına gönderem metot.
{
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","username","password");
        ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AUTHOR(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        ps.setInt(1, id);//ps nesnesine gelen id yi koyduk.
        ps.setString(2, name);//ps nesnesine gelen alanı koyduk.
        ps.setString(3, surname);
        i=ps.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(Exception e)//Hata olduğunda konsola verilecek.
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally //Ne olursa olsun her koşulda çalışacak kısım
    {
        try{
            con.close();
            ps.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(id);
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println(surname);
    return "Authors";
}
```

For the normal ordering what should be my sql statement
 If this question is so simple I am sorry. But I could not find any good answer at google for this.
Thanks

Comment: Unless your query contains an `ORDER BY`, i.e. `SELECT * FROM author ORDER BY id`, there is no "default order".  Rows may be returned in the order they were inserted.  But they may not be returned in that order for a number of reasons.  If you care about the order in which rows are displayed, you'd need to specify the order in your `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select data from table you will not be guaranteed to get the data in same insert order

Always use the order by to get your data in the order you want

```
select * from your_table order by ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are right when showing data in jsf screen. But in Oracle database ordering is 1 3 2. it should be 1 2 3 how can I do that. can not it be done? What if we have a trigger or procedure that order them when a new data is written to database. How can I implement this trigger

Comment: you can ensure order only by using order by

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. In select statement I use ORDER BY and I saw the right order in jsf page.